# Partition by multiple aggregated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (SupplierID int, CustomerID int, SupplierDate datetime, TestColumn1 varchar(10), TestColumn2 varchar(10))
INSERT INTO Test values (1,1, '2010-01-01', 'Apple', 'Banana')
INSERT INTO Test values (1,2, '2006-01-01', 'Pear', 'Grape')
INSERT INTO Test values (2,1, '2004-01-01', 'Carrot', 'Pea')
INSERT INTO Test values (2,2, '2004-01-01', 'Monday', 'Friday')
```

Please see the SQL below:

```
select SupplierID, CustomerID, Max(SupplierDate) over (partition by SupplierID), TestColumn1, TestColumn2 from test
```

The result as expected is:

```
1   1   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 Apple   Banana
1   2   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 Pear    Grape
2   1   2004-01-01 00:00:00.000 Carrot  Pea
2   2   2004-01-01 00:00:00.000 Monday  Friday
```

I want a result of:

```
1   1   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 Apple   Banana
2   1   2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 Apple   Banana
2   2   2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 Carrot  Pea
1   2   2006-01-01 00:00:00.000 Carrot  Pea
```

i.e. Testcolumn1 and TestColumn2 need to be included in the aggregation.  Is there an easy way to do this with partition by? I have never used partition by before.

The query should get the maximum supplier date and then return the maximum supplier date plus test column 1 and test column 2 for every row with the supplier id in the table.

The query needs to return every row in the table.

Comment: So you want to repeat the first row for each combo of SupplierID and CustomerID twice?

Comment: @shree.pat18, I have amended the question to try and make it clearer.  Could you have another look?

Comment: I have done it, please check ans.

Comment: @w0051977 Shouldn't that be Pear Grape instead of Carrot Pea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done without joins

```
;WITH x as
(
  SELECT SupplierID, CustomerID, SupplierDate,
   CASE WHEN row_number() over (partition by SupplierID order by SupplierDate, 
             customerid desc) = count(*) over (partition by SupplierID) 
     then '' end z,
  TestColumn1, TestColumn2 
  FROM test
)
SELECT SupplierID, CustomerID, 
MAX(SupplierDate) over (partition by SupplierID) SupplierDate,
MAX(TestColumn1 + z) over (partition by SupplierID) TestColumn1,
MAX(TestColumn2 + z) over (partition by SupplierID) TestColumn2
FROM x
```

Result:

```
SupplierID  CustomerID      SupplierDate    TestColumn1     TestColumn2
1           2               2010-01-01      Apple           Banana
1           1               2010-01-01      Apple           Banana
2           2               2004-01-01      Carrot          Pea
2           1               2004-01-01      Carrot          Pea
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
;With CTE as 
(
select SupplierID
    , CustomerID
    , Max(SupplierDate) over (partition by CustomerID) as SupplierDate
    , TestColumn1
    , TestColumn2 
from test
)
Select a.SupplierID,a.CustomerID,a.SupplierDate,b.TestColumn1,b.TestColumn2 from CTE as a
inner join Test as b on a.SupplierDate = b.SupplierDate
    and a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
```

Second method,

```
select a.SupplierID,a.CustomerID,a.SupplierDate,b.TestColumn1,b.TestColumn2  from Test as a
outer apply
    (
        select top 1  * from Test 
        where Test.CustomerID = a.CustomerID
        order by SupplierDate desc
    )as b
order by a. CustomerID
```

Comment: The query needs to return every row in the table.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: So what is happening now? I got 4 rows.

Comment: I think query is giving exactly same output that you have given.

Comment: Hey friend can you tell me what is lacking in my output?